# Instantiate multiple spiders from a single class in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

In the interest of saving time and lines of repeated code on a very large project, I have been attempting to instantiate multiple spiders in Scrapy from a single class definition. I don't find in the docs that this is a standard practice, but I also don't find any indication that it cannot or should not be done. However, it is not working. Here is what I'm trying:

```
from scrapy.spider import CrawlSpider

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):

    def __init__(self, name, source, allowed_domains, starturls):
        self.name = name
        self.custom_settings = {'LOG_FILE':'logs/' + name + '.txt' }
        self.source = source
        self.allowed_domains = allowed_domains   
        self.start_urls = starturls
        self.rules = ( Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=''), callback='parse_item', follow=True),) 

     def parse_item(self, response):
        # do stuff here

SpiderInstance = ExampleSpider (
  'columbus',
  'Columbus Symphony',
  'columbussymphony.com',
 [ 'http://www.columbussymphony.com/events/'],  
)
```

The error I get is :

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(execute())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in execute
_run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 90, in _run_print_help
func(*a, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 157, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 170, in crawl
crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 198, in create_crawler
return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 202, in _create_crawler
spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 71, in load
raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: columbus'
```

Is it possible to use Scrapy this way, and if so, what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: did you add this code at the top from scrapy import Spider

Comment: Ahh, good point -- but yes I did. I'll add that to the question for clarity.

Comment: may be you should try this way. from scrapy.spider import CrawlSpider

Comment: Didn't you get a longer error message than that? Post the entire stack trace so we can easily spot which line goes bad.

Comment: You need `super().__init__()`  the `CrawlSpider` class in there somewhere.

Comment: Added the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @starrify's answer, a simple solution I hadn't gone to before:

```
def class_factory(passed_name, passed_source, passed_allowed_domains, passed_start_urls):

   class ColumbusSpider(ExampleSpider):
       name = passed_name
       source = passed_source
       allowed_domains = passed_allowed_domains   
       start_urls = passed_start_urls
       # ... other stuff
       def parse_item(self, response):
           # use any other passed parameters as needed

   return ColumbusSpider

columbus = class_factory ( 
'columbustest',
'Columbus Symphony',
['columbussymphony.com'], 
[ 'http://www.columbussymphony.com/events/'],    
) # use as many times as needed
```

Answer (score 2):

1.

`scrapy` looks for spider *classes*, not *instances*.

Here in your code `ExampleSpider` is a *class*, while `SpiderInstance` is an *instance* of it.

You may need to do something like this instead:

```
class ColumbusSpider(ExampleSpider):
    name = 'columbus'
    source = 'Columbus Symphony'
    allowed_domains = ['columbussymphony.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.columbussymphony.com/events/']
```

2.

It's also worth noticing that the `allowed_domains` attribute of a spider is expected to contain a list, tuple, or set of domains. While in your sample code it's a string.

3.

Instead of subclassing the `ExampleSpider` as shown in #1, you may also make `ExampleSpider` a metaclass. So that instantiating `ExampleSpider` would bring you a class, instead of a class instance.

Comment: #1 results in the situation I'm trying to avoid: repeating "name = ...", "source = ...", and so on, for every spider. There must be a way to pass these values in as arguments rather than write them out manually for every spider. Likewise my spider methods (parse_item, etc.) are reusable if they could receive parameters to customize their behavior per spider. Otherwise I'm just copying and pasting class definitions and altering their details, hundreds of times. Option 3 sounds like what I'm looking for. Could you elaborate on how to apply it?